# ubuntu zone transfer error

Tags: dns, bind

I transferred files from my Windows Server 2019 into ubuntu and I checked the logs and it says "transfer success", but when I try to cat the zone file it displays in binary format any ideas.

My `named.conf.local` file looks like this

```
zone "cambonu.net" {
    type slave;
    file "db.cambonu.net";
    masters { 192.168.114.80; }; // IP address of my Windows DNS server
};
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks like you are new.  This topic is a bit complicated and requires more than a few sentences.  Ref: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask.  Rather than images, I suggest copying text and formatting it using the { } codeblock symbols.  Please clearly state 1. what you are trying to do 2. what happens when it doesn't work and 3. log entries that apply.

Comment: You did not transfer files, you transferred a DNS zone, seems also to have been successful. What is then the problem? Named picks its own fileformat

Comment: So how do copy the zone files then like my A records and all from windows to ubuntu